# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator in first select

Tags: oracle

hi kindly refer to the shared requirement, which i have to display. the error is occuring bcoz of statement below both count . I have to sub both cnt

[image]

```
 of_study_sites_without_rand_subj_gt AS
(
SELECT 
            tu.tu_status, tu.tr_no,
          case when ((asswors- SSWORGT30) then 'of_study_sites_without_rand_subject<30_days' END) SSW0RLT30
          , case when ((asswors- SSWORGT60) then 'of_study_sites_without_rand_subject<30_days' END) SSW0RLT60
          , case when ((asswors- SSWORGT90) then 'of_study_sites_without_rand_subject<30_days' END) SSW0RLT90
            from
( SELECT 
            tu.tu_status, tu.tr_no,           
   COUNT ( CASE WHEN tue.fst_init_vst_act_dt IS NOT NULL THEN tr.tr_alias_cd END ) act_study_site_init,
   COUNT ( CASE WHEN tue.fst_subj_rnd_act IS NOT NULL AND tu.tu_status= 'recruiting' THEN tr.tr_alias_cd END ) actual_with_rnd_rec,
 CASE WHEN (((act_study_site_init) - (actual_with_rnd_rec) AND tu.tu_status= 'nonrecruiting' then 'act_study_site_without_rnd_subj' END) asswors,
  CASE WHEN tue.fst_subj_rnd_act IS NULL then trunc(sysdate)- trunc(tue.fst_init_vst_act_dt )
      else  trunc ( tue.fst_subj_rnd_act ) - trunc ( tue.fst_init_vst_act_dt )
            END daycal,          
    case when daycal>=30 then count(tr.tr_alias_cd) END SSWORGT30 --of study sites without randomised subject ≥ 30 days
           , case when daycal>=60 then count(tr.tr_alias_cd) END SSWORGT60  --of study sites without randomised subject ≥ 60 days
           , case when daycal>=30 then count(tr.tr_alias_cd) END SSWORGT90  --of study sites without randomised subject ≥ 90 days            
  FROM da_cox.dm_ctm_tu tu      
        INNER JOIN da_cox.dm_ctm_tr tr ON tr.tr_no = tu.tr_no
        LEFT OUTER JOIN da_cox.df_ctm_tu_evnt tue 
ON tue.curr_flg = 1
   AND tue.tu_id = tu.tu_id
 WHERE
        tu.curr_flg = 1 /* Study sites that have been cancelled after initiation are counted as initiated */
    GROUP BY
        tu.tr_no,
        tu.tu_status,
        tr.tr_alias_cd
```

Getting error in first select

```
case when ((asswors- SSWORGT30) then 'of_study_sites_without_rand_subject<30_days' END) SSW0RLT30
```

Comment: Getting error in first select  case when ((asswors- SSWORGT30) then 'of_study_sites_without_rand_subject<30_days' END) SSW0RLT30

Comment: From the error it is clear that issue is not related to SQL Server. It is related to Oracle. Please tag database again.

Comment: Please do not post errors in the comments section, edit your original question. Now it **doesn't contain any question at all**, just a list of poorly formatted code which does not even work (with little effort to edit it). Also include [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

This error message indicates the problem lies in this part of the statement:

```
when ((asswors- SSWORGT30) then
```

You have a test but no condition. The statement expects something like

```
when ((asswors- SSWORGT30) <= 30 then
```

That is, if the result of the given sum is less than or equal 30 your case statement will return the string you have after THEN.